# Excel Error 5 when setting RGB values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created this VBA script using a macro recorder. When I change the G or B parameters
to anything other than 0 I get a "Invalid procedure call or argument (Error 5)"

This seems strange as the valid values are 0 to 255?

Any ideas?

```
Sub Change_Colour_1()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce. https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWhhp.png

Comment: Thanks for trying. I am using Excel on MacOs on MacBook Air M1. So I wonder if its simply an incompatibility...